# How would you copy a .JPG file from an ios device's files to a pc?

Tags: c#

I am just trying to get a picture from the iphone's file system and copy that file to my computer. I have research for atleast 10 hours on this yet no luck.

I know c# and prefer this answer to connected to visual studio if possible.

I have download `MobileDevice.dll` and was able to locate successfully the file location and determine that the file does exist.

The next step would be just copying this file.

Maby something like System.IO.File.Copy(iphonepath, "c:\Users\Brandan\Desktop")?

But what would be the iphonepath? The iphone is connected through a port so maby that way?

Comment: Do you mean from the camera roll, or from some random file location?

Comment: If this is a photo from the Photos app, you could email it to yourself...

Comment: This is files from both the DCIM folder and another path that I compile into one. Also I could email the photos to myself but my goal is so save space and do this with code.

Comment: the path im getting photos from based off of MobileDevice.dll is /PhotoData/MetaData/DCIM/100APPLE

Comment: Also, your app is in the desktop pc or inside the iPad?

Comment: How did you check that the file exists?

Comment: The app is made with visual studio on the desktop, I checked by using the code from the .dll reference.